# I want to use a customized name in the sender name while sending Amazon SES email

Tags: gmail, amazon-ses

I want to use a customized name in the sender name while sending Amazon SES email.

Am using the Amazon SES email 
{X-SES-SOURCE-ARN: arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:123456789012:identity/no-reply@example.com}

the sender name shown **no-reply**. so how I change the no-replay name?

instead of I want to use some custom name in my sender address..

can anyone help to change the sender name from "reply-to" to "xxxx"